# A sed script that inserts spaces between field in a fixed length encoded record without delimiters?

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, fixed-width

I have records like this

```
000000000011111111112222222222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeee
```

where there are no delimiters, and I want to read this into a bash script array. If there were delimiters I could just say

```
IFS='|' record=($line)
```

and that would be the end of it. But when the fields are fully populated there are no delimiters.

So I thought I'd make a quick sed script

```
IFS='|' record=( $( echo "$line" |sed 's/\(...\)/\1 /g' ) )
```

which would -- in this case -- put a space delimiter between equal length fields of 3 characters.

But my field widths vary!

```
IFS='|' record=( $( echo "$line" |sed 's/\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{3\}\)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 /g' ) )
```

easy! But not possible in my case because I have more than 9 fields!

I guess there must be some way with sed to control the `s/.../.../g` behavior so that you could do 3 x width of 10 and then 10 times width of 3, or whatever the field lengths are. But I just never really remember how this is done with sed and the man page is notoriously uneducative.

I figure I could do it by making a loop and then read each field with `read -n $width` and build up my own array. This is what I'll do, but I'd prefer some one-shot way of doing it. Would be really easy if there was a scanf(1) command available in the shell environment just like there is a printf(1) command, or if bash `read -a` had an -n 10,10,10,3,3,3* format string or something like that.

Comment: how many records? 10? 1,000? 1,000,000,000,000 ?

Comment: `But my field widths vary!` How do you know the width of every of the fields? `had an -n 10,10,10,3,3,3* format string` _You_ seem to know the widths, should we assume they are "known"?

Comment: you can also try  awk's `FIELDWIDTHS`  operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work from the right to left, this `sed` should produce the expected results for the example data.

```
$ array=($(sed -E 's/(.{3})/\1 /g10;s/(.{10})/\1 /2;s/(.{10})/\1 /' input_file))
```

`s/(.{3})/\1 /g10` - This will deal with the 10x3 widths initially starting at the 30th character inserting a space every 3rd character.

`s/(.{10})/\1 /2;s/(.{10})/\1 /` The remaining 30 characters at the start will now be split into 3x10 once again from right to left.

Echoing the array created, the result is as follows.

```
$ echo ${array[@]}
0000000000 1111111111 2222222222 333 444 555 666 777 888 999 aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
```

Comment: I liked the bash answer above more for my purpose but you answered the question I actually asked, so you deserve the accept.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to create a bash array, using an external tool like `sed` is  suboptimal. You'd have to parse the input twice, first using the external tool, and then bash. It is safer, more efficient, and probably easier to do everything in bash.

Bash's built-in `[[` can match regexes using `=~`. The matched groups are stored in the array `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
printf -v regex '(.{0,%s})' 10 10 10 3 3 3 3
line=000000000011111111112222222222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeee
[[ "$line" =~ ^$regex ]]
fields=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
```

This ignores characters exceeding the specified fields and leaves (partially) empty array entries if the specified fields exceed the line. But you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you for your good intentions, but the `,` is actually a critical part in case the specified fields exceed `$line`. Without `,` you won't match anything. With `,` you match as much fields as possible from left to right, just like `read` would do.

Comment: fair enough and apologies but ... cutting-n-pasting your entire code (with the `,`) into my `bash` (4.4.12) console I get: `typeset -p fields` => `declare -a fields=()` ... nothing

Comment: Hm, strange. I tested this in bash [4.4.12](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php), [4.4.23](https://tio.run/##PY1NC4JAGITv@ytexDChDc3vQMgi8NKluonFrvtagphoSCD217fC8JlhTsMMZ@1dSv5NoLTDpi0eFSF1U1TPHGgHDd7wBdp82S9m7aBrYBp/W6NIWVQYGhPmxGrCsizbth3HcV3X8zzf94MgYIxxzrMsE0IgIkkSUNTfmALhGy7q@JymJC@wFG04V9R@G53i63F/iM67ONmka3NQdCIwK1mDQGsYq1J@AA), [5.0.17](https://onlinegdb.com/isbSVQUOf), 5.1.8 and got the expected `fields` everywhere. Does it work for you if you replace `{,%s}` by `{0,%s}`?

Comment: yes, works with `{0,%s}`; thanks

Comment: Thank you for checking this. Then `{0,%s}` seems to be the better option. I updated the answer. Still wondering what caused the difference between your bash and the seemingly same version on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php).

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. I first gave you the accept, but then I found @HatLess answered my actual question with sed, so that answer deserved the accept.

Answer (score 2):

One idea using `GNU awk` and `FIELDWIDTHS` to introduce delimiters:

```
x='000000000011111111112222222222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeee'

awk '
BEGIN { OFS="|"                                              # define output delimiter
        FIELDWIDTHS = "10 10 10 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3"     # define width of each field
      }
      { $1=$1                                                # force an evaluation so that fields are parsed
        print 
      }
' <<< "${x}"
```

This generates:

```
0000000000|1111111111|2222222222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999|aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|eee
```

From here you can do what you want with the `|` delimited data (eg, read into an array).

**NOTES:**

- `FIELDWIDTHS` is *just* a variable so for processing inputs with a variable number of fields you could certainly generalize this `awk` script and pass in a string to define `FIELDWIDTHS`
- for this example we used a single variable (`x`) but we could just as easily feed a file to the `awk` script to add delimiters to all input lines
- if required in several places it shoul be easy enough to wrap this in a user-defined function

Comment: Yes, really good point, I should have done the whole project in AWK to begin with. I am a minimalist and love to start with shell, but AWK would have been the better tool for the tasks to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Perl's [`unpack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack) function.

For small number of records, you could do (using your sample line):

```
IFS='|' record=($(perl -ple '$_=join"|",unpack"(a10)3(a3)12"' <<<"$line"))
```

Because it runs a new `perl` process for every line, if you have many, it would be more efficient to wrap in a loop along lines of:

```
perl -ple '$_=join"|",unpack"(a10)3(a3)12"' inputfile |\
while IFS='|' read -ra record; do
    : process ${record[@]}
done
```

(assumes the fixed-width records are delimited by newlines)